# cv qualifiers in concept requires expression parameter list

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-expression

I have the following code using concepts:

```
struct bar {
    void foo() {}
};

template <typename T>
concept Fooable = requires (const T& t) { // const bar& t doesn't support t.foo()
    { t.foo() };
};

template <typename Fooable>
void callfoo(Fooable bar)
{
    bar.foo();
}

int main()
{
    bar b;
    callfoo(b);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the code not to compile as `bar` does not support calling `foo()` on a const instance. However it does compile fine - [link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b5oMjq).

The parameter list description on cppreference isn't much helpful in this regard:

> parameter-list  -   a comma-separated list of parameters like in a function declaration, except that default arguments are not allowed and it cannot end with an ellipsis (other than one signifying a pack expansion). These parameters have no storage, linkage or lifetime, and are only used to assist in specifying requirements. These parameters are in scope until the closing } of the requirement-seq.

Am I misunderstanding what the cv-qualifiers are for in a requires expression parameter list? Am I missing something entirely? I am further confused by cppreference having some examples making use of universal reference parameters so there must be some point in it.

I am using `gcc9` with `-fconcepts` (though gcc trunk and clang with concepts on godbolt are fine with this code as well so don't assume it's compiler related).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bug in your `callfoo` function. You are using a typename, not a concept. Change the declaration to either

```
template <Fooable Foo>
void callfoo(Foo bar)
```

or

```
void callfoo(Fooable auto bar)
```

Comment: Note that once the appropriate correction is made, [the code fails to compile as expected](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LSVLrA).

Comment: @inf :D I only noticed it at the third look aswell.